# Azure DevOps: Backlog view for multiple teams

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agile-project-management, agile-processes

Here is my understanding of Azure DevOps so far.

In our project X, we have 63 teams. And each team has its own area path and a backlog view.

We plan to have a monthly sync with all big rock owners. We will cover current progress, and plan for the next month by looking at "Active" Epics and Features.

Each of these owners are from different teams, so I need to see a view of their big rocks, epics and features under them. Since they all have their own area/team as area paths, how can I have a single view of all of this in a single board?

Constraints: We don't want to display all features at this point as there could be gazillions of them. So, we want to display Big Rocks --> Epics --> Features that they are currently working on. Is "State" a good filter to use to display only Active features? Any other alternative solutions?

Comment: What is a "big rock"?

Comment: @DanielMann Just like how User Stories get rolled up into Features. Features get rolled up into Epics. And Epics into something called Big Rocks in our organization.

Comment: Did State work? You can also try using query.